# Jquery dynamic background image url does not work

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, background-image

I want to display different background-images from my background image folder when a user refreshes a page or clicks different pages.

In my layout i'm caching my image's path but i could not make jquery to show it properly. background-position and background-attachment attributes are working but background-image is not being created by jquery. It's like jquery skips background-image code.

By the way my backgroundUrl property creates like a path "/images/background/1.jpg" so it's properly working. Thanks for any help.

```
@{

    var items = Utils.GetImages("background", 3);
    var backgroundUrl = items.FirstOrDefault();

}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (backgroundUrl) {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundUrl + ')',
            'background-position': '50% 0%', 'background-attachment': 'fixed'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why is `backgroundUrl` an argument in jQuery's DOM ready function ?

Comment: You cannot pass variables in Razor like above in dom ready function. Use `@backgroundUrl `

Comment: I was following similar solutions. do you have better idea to do what i intent to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use variable in jquery script
"@variable name"

```
@{

    var items = Utils.GetImages("background", 3);
    var backgroundUrl = items.FirstOrDefault();

}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + "@backgroundUrl.ToString()" + ')',
            'background-position': '50% 0%', 'background-attachment': 'fixed'
        });
    });
</script>
```